# Code that seems right, but has an invalid syntax that i can't figure out

Tags: python-2.7

I have this code:

```
    print ("Hello",name"I am Zero V11. How may i assist you?")
```

(Name is a variable) Every time I try to run this code I get the error :
 "EOL while scanning string literal", this seems to be for the entire line of code.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma between `name` and the last string.

Try

```
print("Hello", name, "I am Zero V11. How may i assist you?")
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer to indicate that it worked.